# Comments Social Plugin Comments not posting on wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, facebook-wall

I am currently trying to use the Facebook Comment Social plugin for comments on my site. Almost everything works, the comments can be seen by people on the site and also viewable using http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments. And the "Post to Facebook" checkbox is checked. However, the comments are still not posted on the news feed or wall or anything at all of the person commenting.

"Make every post public by default". setting is selected on moderator. and the  is present in all pages.

Why is that? Have I missed anything? Please help...

Note: I cannot give the URL of the site since it is not yet uploaded to a public server and am just testing it on my PC with the router on port forwarding. I think the router is properly configured since my friends can access the site given the proper IP address.